# Error: missing tool for os.windows.x86_32 in meteor-tool@1.6.0

Tags: meteor, upgrade

Just upgraded meteor on `Windows 10`.

- Uninstalled old version.
- Deleted old AppData/local/.meteor directory
- Reinstalled using choco install meteor

Now when I attempt to update my old project I get the following error message.

```
Error: missing tool for os.windows.x86_32 in meteor-tool@1.6.0
```

How can I solve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Got the same error. Manually changing the release to METEOR@1.6 caused tons of other problems, so I wish this could be fixed first by the Meteor Dev Group

Comment: Some of those problems may just be 1.6 compatibility problems.  Ultimately, I had to fix this by creating a new 1.6 project, and migrating my code into it step by step.  At various steps, I found that packages I was using (both meteor + npm) no longer worked or needed some code changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a correct behavior, but I've managed to fix this by editing project's .meteor/release and replacing its content by

> METEOR@1.6

Then I've executed "meteor" (without "update") and it installed/upgraded the necessary packages. The project I'm currently developing starts and works ok so far.

Comment: This kinda worked, but ultimately, I had to create a new Meteor 1.6 project, and migrate all my code into it.

Answer (score 3):

Using the command 

`meteor update --release 1.6`

solved the same problem for me. Try this.